# Load Gnome Tweaks settings on login or reset

Tags: gnome-shell, gnome-tweaks

I have a 4K monitor, and use (Gnome) Tweaks in Ubuntu Desktop 20.04 to set interface font scaling to 1.80. Sometime during the spring/summer months of 2020 Gnome Desktop (using X11 v3.36.3) started ignoring saved Tweaks settings. Due to the 4k, this makes the interface stupidly difficult to read when I first log in until I manually go to Tweaks and then decrement/increment the font scaling back to 1.80.

Around the same time (spring/summer 2020) Gnome Desktop using X11 became even more unstable than it usually is (at least with my NVIDIA-driven GPU) on login (e.g., garbled text, visual artifacts/distortions, etc.). I therefore frequently resort to <kbd>F2</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>, and then run `r` to reset Gnome. When I do this, again Tweeks settings are ignored and I have to manually reset the font scaling.

**How can I force Gnome to respect Tweaks settings?**

Comment: I am voting to close myquestion because it already has [more](https://askubuntu.com/q/1262135/909490) than one [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1269090/ubuntu-20-04-interface-font-too-small-after-restart-even-with-high-scaling-fact).